# HTML form with textarea for email recipient with access to address book (like on youtube)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I just shared a video on youtube via mail and noticed that the recipient field for the email addess has access to my computers address book. While I type, I get suggestions for email addresses from my address book.

I'd like to know how this is done. I am using Safari and Mac OS X Mountain Lion. Is this some special Safari Javscript magic?

A plain HTML 5 field of type email does not show this behavior.

Comment: @adeneo and, significantly, Google owns YouTube too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google owns YouTube, and your Google account is linked to your YouTube account.  They can do whatever they want.

Comment: Oh man... Thanks :) Stupid me. It's always the simplest solution